# How to include spaces for a star program

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

The problem asks to create a pattern like below using nested while loops.

```
********
  ********
******** 
  ********
********
  ********
********
  ********
```

I can print out stars, but they look like this:

```
********
********
******** 
********
********
********
********
********
```

Is there a way to include spaces in the beginning of stars without disrupting the rest of the pattern?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
    int star=0;
int n=8;
int space=n-1;
int counter=0;
while(counter<8){
    while(star<n){
        star=star+1;
        {if(counter%2==0)
            cout<< "*";
        else cout<<"*";
        }

}
    counter=counter+1;
    star=0;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

(Note: What I tried to do is to take the row number, and add a space if it was odd)
Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: So I just realized you can't see the stars. The stars are in a 8by8 rectangle, and the even row stays the same, but the odd row number gets indented. I'm not sure how to add add spaces to it. Sorry about that.

Comment: You have both branches of your if statement printing asterisks, so there will never be a space printed. Maybe other issues, but this one seems to stand out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help should help you with [edit]ing your question to make it appear as you want it. While you are at it get rid of unnecessary formatting, empty lines etc.

Comment: Look at your `if`code and explain the difference between "then" and "else". I don't see any.

Comment: Aside from the actual problem, note that there are `for` loops, which fit better in a context in which you simply want to count up. A way shorter version for the whole thing: `for(int i=0; i<8; i++) { if(i%2 == 0) { cout << string(2, ' '); } cout << string(8, '*') << endl; }`.

Comment: A space in the source code between the stream operator `<<` and the actual value does not do anything. You need to add the space inside the value, e.g. `" *"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code with less space usage. And its providing an output as you want.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){ 
    int n=8;

    while(n--){
        int m = 8;
        if(n%2!=0){
            while(m--){
                cout<<"*";
            }
        }
        else{
            cout<<"  ";
            while(m--){
                cout<<"*";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int star = 0;
  int n = 8;
  int space = n - 1;
  int counter = 1;
  while (counter < 8) {
    if (counter % 2 == 0) { // If statement should be before line printing code
      cout << " ";
    }

    while (star < n) {
      star = star + 1;
      cout << "*";
    }

    counter = counter + 1;
    star = 0;
    cout << endl; // cout was doubled
  }

  return 0;
}
```